# Bro IDS searches

Tags: python, perl, bro

I have never used Python or Perl before. I got a project from work due to unforeseen circumstances and am hoping one of you guys can help. We use BRO for an IDS System. I am supposed to write a script that will open a log file (in .gz format), search the log for a list of keywords saved in a text file, exclude any results that have keywords listed in another file, and then output those results into a new .gz. It is supposed to run 3 times per day. I am not sure where to start but any help would be incredibly helpful and greatly appreciated.

Comment: lol ... you used alot of words that make sense to me (and most of stack overflow) individually ... however when put together like this you have confused 99.9% of stack overflow about what your question even is ... I think we need more background at the very least

Comment: ahh I think I see now what your question is

Comment: Sorry If I am being confusing. We collect HTTP logs using Bro. I need to write a code that searches those HTTP logs for a list of keywords, then excludes any results from another lists of keywords and then outputs the results. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahh after several re-reads I think I start to see the question ... *IDS and BRO just are totally irrellevant to the question* **and actually confuse the matter**

I think I can decompose your question down into several sub-questions

Question 1.**How do I open a gzip encoded file for reading?**

```
import gzip
with gzip.GzipFile("/path/to/some_log_file.gz") as input_plaintext_filehandle:
     for line in input_plaintext_filehandle:
         print line
```

Question 2. **How do I write to a gzip file?**

```
import gzip
with gzip.GzipFile("/path/to/some_log_file.gz","w") as output_file:
     output_file.write("Hello GZIP World")
```

Question 3. **How Do I Filter out lines based on a wordlist.txt?**

```
words = set(open("wordlist.txt").read().split())
for line in open_file_handle:
    if words.intersection(line.split()):
       print "Match Found"
    else:
       print "No Match Found"
```

I think this should give you enough to get started on solving this problem.  feel free to come back once you get stuck and have some code to show

Comment: This is great, thank you!